# Symbian Power Status Notification

Tags: symbian, notifications, sleep, wakeup

I have an application that uses memory card and I need to do some save/restore state operations when the power of the card reader is turned off and on back again. This usually happens after some time of activity and phone goes to a power save mode. In Windows Mobile I solved the same problem by receiving power notifications from the system and take the appropriate action. I would like to know if there is an equivalent of this messages in Symbian?

To clarify, I am not interested in current status of ac cable connected, battery level. I just want to receive notifications before phone goes to sleep mode and after it wakes up.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to use the User Inactivity timer, which is the stimulus for the device dropping to power-save mode: [See Forum Nokia](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Detecting_user_inactivity_in_Symbian_OS)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, seems like it might work. I will give it a try.